# What are advantages to use the frameworks like Laravel , Yii2 , Slim etc.?

Tags: php, rest

Provide me the advantages and disadvantages

Comment: it's a shame those scrum masters were slamming the "opinion based" button. Because the answer given, does not seem alright. Basically LARAVEL is a beast. More comparable to say, Symfony. Slim is a micro framework. It gives you easy routing, easy access to request and response objects, middleware. Apart from that, it is up to YOU what you include. You want to include Laravels database ORM? no problem. You want to use twig for "beautiful templating" ? no problem. You don't want to deal with all the rest you consider crap? no problem.

Answer (score 4):

I think its best to use LARAVEL rather than SLIM since Laravel have the best support,documentation,tutorials and examples available comparing to Slim.
Besides, Laravel Restful API is more and widely used than Slim

Laravel Framework Advantages

Laravel PHP Framework also offers many features such as:

```
MVC, HMVC
    Bundles
    RESTful Routing
    The Eloquent ORM
    Application Logic
    Beautiful Templating
    Migrations
    Unit Testing
    Authentication
    ACI
    Caching
    Hooks / Events
    Admin Generation
    Scaffolding
    Validation
    Automatic Pagination
```

**REFERENCE** :

http://www.sitepoint.com/goodbye-codeigniter-hello-laravel/

http://www.comentum.com/laravel-developers.html

Comment: I disagree. Using laravel for creating rest api is an OVERKILL. Slim is a php micro-framework which is best for creating restful apis. It also gives you a restful and easy routing and like toskan said "it is up to YOU what you include". So yeah if you're JUST CREATING A REST API, I prefer SLIM, but if you're creating a big website, laravel is the choice.

Comment: I totally agree Vashtamyty -- if you just want to design APIs, use Slim; and you will gain in performance.